# WCF Windows Service and Windows Store App Non-Meaningful Reply Error Message

Tags: wcf, windows-store-apps

I'm having a lot of problems getting tyres on the ground with Windows 8 Programming.

One problem is, I cannot install IIS as Windows 8 is giving me problems because I am dual booting it with 7. Any OS updates fail, including configuration changes such as adding IIS.

But anyway, to get around this, I decided to host a WCF service in a Windows Service with a TCP endpoint, and consume that service in my Store app. For inserts, it works, not a problem.

But when I go to retrieve some data (a very small data set - 3 records), the following error displays: *The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error*.

I've Googled that error and it seems to be a common one - meaning it could be anything. But I am a total noob with WCF.

My code in the ViewModel is simply:

```
    private async void PopulatePeople()
    {
        var people = await licenceBucketService.GetAllPersonsAsync();

        FirstName = people.First().FirstName;
        LastName = people.First().LastName;
    }
```

The GetAllPersons method is:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> GetAllPersons()
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> people = null;

    using (var context = new LicenceBucketContext())
    {
         people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(context.People);
    }

    return people;
}
```

The async version in the Reference.cs file looks like:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Win8UI.LicenceBucketService.Person>> GetAllPersonsAsync() {
        return base.Channel.GetAllPersonsAsync();
    }
```

Do any WCF gurus see my issue?

Comment: The first thing I would look for is a contract mismatch.  Have you made any changes to your OperationContracts or DataContracts on the server side and forgot to reference the newly compiled contracts assembly on the client side?  Or are you using a service reference and need to update the service reference to the latest code change?

Comment: @TylerOhlsen I uninstalled the service, deleted the reference to it, recompiled it and installed it again. I then added the fresh service reference and made sure the host was running. With all that, still no luck.

Comment: We need GetAllPersons method service implementation code to see/check

Comment: @SalientBrain I have edited my post to include that method.

Comment: I think problem is in Using statement. Create LicenceBucketContext ones per service instance/session or statically

Comment: @SalientBrain I did something just as good. I forced the context to execute by calling ToList() on the People object. I still get the same message. I'm having a lot of trouble debugging this as no symbols are loading for that method in the DataService.

Comment: Why are you using ObservableCollection here? - its useless.

Comment: @SalientBrain OK. I have changed the service so it now returns a List of Person objects. The behavior has not changed. I am assuming that some code generator is generating the GetAllPersonsAsync method. So, why is that generated code broken?

Comment: You always get strange errors when you transmit objects that cannot be serialized or deserialized. Did you try to return an empty list to your client, to see if that works? If it doesn't work, pick another return type. Make it simpler until it works to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks for that. It seems I could not see the forest for the trees. A simple method returning an int works fine. One of the EF entities I'm returning has an ICollection member and I'm guessing interfaces are not serializable. I was under the wrong assumption that EF entities were serializable. That, coupled with WCF noobness and the async aspect distracted me from the real problem. Thanks heaps.